# Libgdx more than one Scissor

Tags: libgdx, rendering

So I have a question: Is it possible to use more than one Scissor at the same time? I want to cut squared "holes" inside one of my actor but I can't find any example.

Here is what i want to achieve: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EE9R.jpg
And I've calculated this 3 rectangles already :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the scissor stack you can push several scissor rectangles and then render.
See how it is done in the doc and then create all the rectangles you need.

(https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Clipping,-with-the-use-of-scissorstack).

Comment: Here is what i want to achieve: http://imgur.com/zsxOWLc
And I've calculated this 3 rectangles already :)

Comment: Ah sorry I did not understand what you want to achieve, I edited answer accordingly.